# Using pivot query in PHP to SQL Server get error TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I've a problem in my query SQL in PHP when I run this code it's work fine:

```
$query_sql = "
                    select c_delivery,c_labor,c_packing,c_taxes,c_trucking,c_deploy,c_insurance,insert_ts,expense_id, REPLACE(tca_no,'?','') AS tca_no, trip_id, CURR 'Currency', total_amount 'ExpenseTotalAmount',
                    manifest, da, 
                    Trip_Expense_Allocation, insert_by, uploaded_at, replace(replace(replace(ltrim(rtrim(lic_no)),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>','-') as lic_no
                    from (select eh.insert_ts,eh.expense_id, eh.tca_no, '' as 'vendor_code', ed.trip_id, tt.lic_no, tm.manifest, td.da, ed.c_delivery, 
                    ed.c_deploy, ed.c_insurance, ed.c_labor, ed.c_packing,
                    ed.c_taxes, ed.c_trucking, 'IDR' 'CURR' , eh.total_amount, CASE  WHEN ed.is_expense_group = 'Y' THEN 'All Trip' ELSE ' ' END as 'Trip_Expense_Allocation',
                    eh.insert_by, getdate() AS uploaded_at
                    from fms.tt_expense_header eh (nolock)
                    left JOIN fms.tt_expense_detail ed (nolock) ON ed.expense_id = eh.expense_id
                    left join fms.tt_trips tt (nolock) on ed.trip_id = tt.trip_id
                    left join fms.tt_manifest tm (nolock) on tm.trip_id = tt.trip_id
                    left join fms.tt_da_mps td (nolock) on td.trip_id = tt.trip_id
                    where eh.is_up_sap = 'N' and eh.tca_no > '0' 
                    --and eh.tca_no in ('327393')
                    --and CAST(eh.insert_ts AS Date) BETWEEN '2021-01-01' and '2021-01-31'
                    and YEAR(CAST(eh.insert_ts AS Date)) >= '2021'
                    --and MONTH(CAST(eh.insert_ts AS Date)) IN '2020'
                    and eh.is_middle IS NULL
                    

                    and eh.tca_request_type = 'trans14'
                    and (tm.manifest IS NOT NULL OR td.da IS NOT NULL)
                    ) p
                    ";
```

But when run this code I get an error:

```
$query_sql = "select expense_id, REPLACE(tca_no,'?','') AS tca_no, trip_id, CURR 'Currency', total_amount 'ExpenseTotalAmount',
                    manifest, da,  ExpenseAmount 'ExpenseType', 
                    CASE
                        WHEN ExpenseAmount = 'COS_DELIVERY' THEN '6016001000' 
                        WHEN ExpenseAmount = 'COS_DEPLOY' THEN '6017014000'
                        WHEN ExpenseAmount = 'COS_INSURANCE' THEN '6030001000'
                         WHEN ExpenseAmount = 'COS_LABOR' THEN '6002001000'
                        WHEN ExpenseAmount = 'COS_PACKING' THEN '6020001000'
                        WHEN ExpenseAmount = 'C_TAXES' THEN '6017011000'
                        WHEN ExpenseAmount = 'C_TRUCKING' THEN '6017008000'
                    END 'GLPostingCode',
                    ExpenseType 'ExpenseAmount', Trip_Expense_Allocation, insert_by, uploaded_at, replace(replace(replace(ltrim(rtrim(lic_no)),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>','-') as lic_no
                    from (select distinct eh.expense_id, eh.tca_no, '' as 'vendor_code', ed.trip_id, tt.lic_no, tm.manifest, td.da, ed.c_delivery 'COS_DELIVERY', 
                    ed.c_deploy 'COS_DEPLOY', ed.c_insurance 'COS_INSURANCE', ed.c_labor 'COS_LABOR', ed.c_packing 'COS_PACKING',
                    ed.c_taxes 'C_TAXES', ed.c_trucking 'C_TRUCKING', 'IDR' 'CURR' , eh.total_amount, CASE  WHEN ed.is_expense_group = 'Y' THEN 'All Trip' ELSE ' ' END as 'Trip_Expense_Allocation',
                    eh.insert_by, getdate() AS uploaded_at
                    from fms.tt_expense_header eh left JOIN
                    fms.tt_expense_detail ed ON ed.expense_id = eh.expense_id
                    left join fms.tt_trips tt on ed.trip_id = tt.trip_id
                    left join fms.tt_manifest tm on tm.trip_id = tt.trip_id
                    left join fms.tt_da_mps td on td.trip_id = tt.trip_id
                    where eh.is_up_sap = 'N' and eh.tca_no > '0' 
                    --and eh.tca_no in ('331386','332055','334682','334689')
                    --and CAST(eh.insert_ts AS Date) BETWEEN '2021-01-01' and '2021-01-31'
                    --and CAST(eh.insert_ts AS Date) = '$date_now'
                    and YEAR(CAST(eh.insert_ts AS Date)) = '2021'
                    and eh.is_middle IS NULL
                                        

                    and eh.tca_request_type = 'trans14'
                    and (tm.manifest IS NOT NULL OR td.da IS NOT NULL)
                    ) p
                    UNPIVOT
                    (
                    ExpenseType for ExpenseAmount IN (COS_DELIVERY, COS_DEPLOY, COS_INSURANCE, COS_LABOR, COS_PACKING, C_TAXES, C_TRUCKING)
                    ) as unpvt
                    order by tca_no,ExpenseAmount";
```

This is the error

> Error (sqlsrv_query): Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08S01 [SQLSTATE]
> => 08S01 [1] => 121 [code] => 121 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired.
> [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]TCP Provider:
> The semaphore timeout period has expired. ) [1] => Array ( [0] =>
> 08S01 [SQLSTATE] => 08S01 [1] => 121 [code] => 121 [2] =>
> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Communication link failure
> [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Communication
> link failure ) )

The difference of both is just on using unpivot. Why do I get this error when I use unpivot?

When I use the second query (unpivot query) in SQL Server it works fine.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: That's quite eminently *not* the only difference with the query. Apart from the differences in the `select` you have an `order by` which is probably slowing it down quite a lot and causing the timeout. There is also an extra `distinct` thrown in for unclear reasons. The `YEAR` check is also different, and clearly indicates you have dates stored in `varchar` columns. **[And stop misusing `NOLOCK`](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)** (You should also not use `''` to quote column names, use `[]` instead)

Comment: ok i understand, thanks @Charlieface